# Ordered statistic calculation with a different kind of cdf

Tags: order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ be I.I.D random variables, and let $Y_{(1)}\leq Y_{(2)} \leq ... \leq Y_{(n)}$ be the ordering of the random variables.The distribution function is given as-
\begin{align*}
F(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 / 2 & \text{for $0 < x < 1$} \\
2x-x^2 / 2 - 1 & \text{for $1 \le x < 2$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The aim is to find out the density function of the lowest order statistic $Y_{(1)}$. I'm completely stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I voted for closing this question as a self-study question with no indication as to why the OP could not apply the formulas found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $F_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right)$ as the distribution function of the lowest order statistic. Then by definition:
$$F_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right) = \operatorname{Pr}\left(Y_{\left(1\right)} \leq x\right)$$
Since $Y_{\left(1\right)} = \min\left\{X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{n}\right\}$, this is the same as asking the probability that *at least* one of $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{n}$ is less than or equal to $x$. Or equivalently, the complement of the probability that *none* of $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots, X_{n}$ are less than or equal to $x$. So by I.I.D., $F_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right)$ can be generally formulated as
$$\begin{align} F_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right) &= 1 - \operatorname{Pr}\left(X_{1} > x\right)^{n} \\ &= 1 - \left[1 - F\left(x\right)\right]^{n} \end{align}$$
Differentiating this to obtain the density function gives
$$f_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right) = n\left[1 - F\left(x\right)\right]^{n - 1}f\left(x\right)$$
Applying it to the given distribution function, we have
$$f_{\left(1\right)}\left(x\right) = \begin{cases} n\left(1 - x^{2}/2\right)^{n - 1}x, & 0 < x < 1 \\  n\left(2 - 2x + x^{2}/2\right)^{n - 1}\left(2 - x\right), & 1 \leq x < 2 \\ 0, & \mathrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: A quick question-Iis finding the lowest ordered statistic equivalent to finding the distribution of $W = min(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Can you please take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090657/ordered-statistics-of-sum-of-uniform-variates). The densities are different.

Comment: I had asked the same question. The cdf here is that of the sum of two i.i.d uniform variates in [0,1].

Comment: In the linked question, the $W$ is the minimum of two dependent random variables.

Comment: Can you please explain how are they linked? It is given in the linked question that $X,Y,Z$ are independent uniform variates.

Comment: $X + Y$ and $Y + Z$ are dependent because they both contain $Y$. So the I.I.D. case would not apply here.